# How can I make oatmeal cookies softer/more chewy?

Tags: eggs, cookies

I am using the [vanishing oatmeal cookie recipe](http://www.quakeroats.com/cooking-and-recipe/vanishing-oatmeal-raisin-cookies.aspx) on the container of Quaker  oatmeal. I do not like the way the cookies turn out. I am looking for a more chewy or softer cookie. It calls for two eggs - would reducing the eggs to one make them more chewy? I'm not experienced in making adjustments to recipes so I'm not sure if the eggs are the problem. I thought they might be the problem because I really loved the results I got from a sugar cookie recipe that only had one egg.

The full ingredients list is:

> 1/2 Cup(s) (1 stick) plus 6 tablespoons butter, softened
>   3/4 Cup(s) firmly packed brown sugar
>   1/2 Cup(s) granulated sugar
>   2 Eggs
>   1 Teaspoon(s) vanilla
>   1-1/2 Cup(s) all-purpose flour
>   1 Teaspoon(s) Baking Soda
>   1 Teaspoon(s) ground cinnamon
>   1/2 Teaspoon(s) salt (optional)
>   3 Cup(s) Quaker® Oats (quick or old fashioned, uncooked)
>   1 Cup(s) raisins

Comment: Your question header and the body of the question contradict one another. If you want softer chewier cookie, an extra egg would help get there.

Comment: I'd say the contradiction that has been pointed out means that I am not experienced in the matter, hence the question, . I suppose I could have asked what is the purpose of eggs in baking cookies. I did bake the best sugar cookies ever right after the oatmeal  with only 1 egg and they had the texture I was going for. Was more than the egg I am sure that created such a perfect cookie! Ill try the oatmeal cookies with an extra egg and see what happens, thanks!

Comment: Well sugar cookies and oatmeal cookies are very different beasts :-) see if you can clarify your question and include the new information you have with the sugar cookies. Right now the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: The oatmeal cookie recipe would help too. Also, old-fashioned or quick-cook oats?

Comment: melting the better might help (so it’s available to make gluten).  Alton Brown covered some of the things that change the texture of cookies in the episode “Three Chips for Sister Martha”, and you can find the transcript at https://web.archive.org/web/20050312134420/http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/Season3/EA1C05.htm

Answer (score 2):

More crunchy without eggs to moisten.

Another factor is how long the mixture sits to absorb the liquid egg before baking. Longer = chewier

I use molasses and white sugar in place of the brown sugar and that also makes them more tender less crunchy.

Also adding 1/2c more oats to recipe will be chewier if they aren't over Baked/dry.

Answer (score 0):

Cornstarch is a good trick to help make cookies more soft and chewy. It helps to bind and hold the moisture after baking.

Increased sugar will also make them more tender.

One egg vs. two eggs won't really make a world of difference, but maybe replace the missing egg with a tablespoon or two of something liquid (milk, maple syrup, water, etc)

Answer (score 0):

My recipe is almost the same but it has ½ C butter and ½ of shortening. IDK just saying. Mine calls for 2½ oats and says for cheery add ½ C yours already says 3 C oats do is try the extra butter/shortening

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First, let me apologize for you feeling inexperienced is bad or even embarrassing. I normally only share my recipes with my Daughter—In—Laws & Granddaughters & I’d never answer their questions with the negative connotation we see above. So I think it’s a great time to share some of my experiences with you. I’m no expert but I’ve found learning bakers can look at recipes with fresh eyes and their search for options often leads to better results YAY FOR US ;-} I also started with the same recipe & changed a bit to fit my tastes.
OPTIONS:

- 1 teaspoon of cornstarch per cup of flour.
- Replace each cup of brown sugar (200 g) with 2/3 cup (160 mL) of liquid sweetener of your choice. I LOVE USING HONEY!!
- For every 2/3 cup (160 mL) of liquid sweetener used, reduce other liquid sources by approximately 1/4 cup (60 mL).
- Adding fruits also adds a wonderful burst of flavor and moisture to every bite! My faves are adding:
- 1 cup broken pecans, 1/2 cup dried cranberries,
- 1/2 cup dried cherries and
- 1 cup raisins.
  *=* Be sure to soak your dried fruits in hot water for a minimum of 20 minutes. I like soaking them for an hour.

Let us know how your treats turn out! I’d like to know any new options you find! Enjoy and God Bless the hands that cook joy into life!!